# How to use more than one setInterval()?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the 'box' in the code move to the right and then go back to the left. I tried to use 2 setInterval but it didn't works (or maybe i don't know how to use 2 `setInterval`).

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var pos = 0;
var toRight = setInterval(move, 10);

function move() {
  if (pos >= 150) {
    clearInterval(toRight);
  } else {
    pos++;
    box.style.left = pos + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I tried so many ways and the code still doesn't run, can some one show me the way to make the 'box' move back from the right side. Thank you.

Comment: Use a single interval but when the box hits a certain position then subtract from `pos` instead of adding to it

Comment: Using two (or more) `setInterval` it's just a matter of making as many calls as you need. But your question is not about setInterval but moving a _box_. I'd suggest rephrasing your question title, edit your question to explain exactly what you want and show what you tried so far (in this case the `setInterval` intent).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code was a good start, and @j08691's comment is the right direction to take it.

Use 1 interval function but keep track of which direction the box is moving and toggle it when desired.

```js
let box = document.getElementById("box");
let pos = 0, right = true;
setInterval(() => {
  pos += right * 2 - 1;
  if (pos === 0 || pos === 150)
    right = !right;
  box.style.left = pos + "px";
}, 10);
```

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
}

#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is `toRight` defined? I'm assuming you meant to assign the return value of `setInterval` to a variable named `toRight`.

Comment: no, i just had leftover pasted code. cleaned it up. We don't need to track `toRight` if we're never going to clear the interval. But if there's some condition after witch you want the box to never move again, then sure, we can keep `toRight`.

Comment: I figured it was unused, since the condition `pos === 0 || pos === 150` would prevent it from being executed, but it was there. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could also use [css animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and skip the javascript part entirely:

```css
@keyframes move {
  from { left: 0; }
  to { left: calc(100% - 50px); }
}

#container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  animation: move 2s linear alternate infinite;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<p id="demo"></p>
```